# react-gocoding returns [object Promise]

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, promise

Help me pleace! I not JS-dev, but I create React App with Google MapsAPI. And I have a problem to use 'react-geocode'.
(Example here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-geocode)
I dont understand how to work with promises from example, and use the getting-address function:

```
Geocode.fromLatLng("48.8583701", "2.2922926").then(
  (response) => {
    const address = response.results[0].formatted_address;
    console.log(address);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.error(error);
  }
);
```

I use it like this:

```
    export function getAddress(lat, lng) {
         return Geocode.fromLatLng(lat, lng).then(
            (response) => {
                let address= response.results[0].formatted_address;
                return address;
            },
            (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        );
    };

   ///app.js

     <p>{"".concat(getAddress(selected.lat, selected.lng))}</p>
```

and have a result `[object, Promise]`, but response is correctly when I view it in debug mode.

Comment: You need to set a state from the callback of the promise, and in your render method handle the case where the result is not yet available.

Comment: thanks, but nothing is clear yet